# Powershell iterate over json blocks in parallel?

Tags: json, powershell, parallel-processing

Given a json file (eg address book), containing many blocks, where each block stores same details (eg for each unique user), is it possible in powershell to iterate over the json blocks in parallel to speed up processing time?

Eg:

```
$addressBook = Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json

ForEach ($user in $addressBook.users) {
   #actions
}

#in parallel?

1..$addressBook.users.count | ForEach-Object -Parallel { #actions } -ThrottleLimit 20
```

Comment: Your parallel code should probably be `$addressBook.users | ForEach-Object -Parallel { #actions } -ThrottleLimit 20`. I've no idea if such objects are thread safe, however, so I'd be cautious about updating the collection itself in a parallel loop. You'd have to experiment to see if it works. Parallelization is not without cost, too, so you may not see a benefit unless the `#actions` are time or CPU intensive rather than IO bound.

Comment: Here's a pretty good article that covers the basics. Though it's from somewhat before PowerShell 7 was released, the concepts are still correct: https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-multithreading/

Comment: Can you give an example of the actions?

Comment: An example of the actions would be, add user values (name, address) to a database, and other I/O related actions involving azure which take time. Hence the need to process users in parallel

Comment: If only the database is getting the changes, I would think it would work.  But I don't have experience with it.